# SignalR authentication security

Tags: token, websocket

I would like to ask a question about security in the case of [SignalR](http://signalr.net/), a library for real-time HTTP communication. I see it as an abstraction layer for web-sockets with fall-back mechanisms in case the browser (or server, or firewall) would not support web-sockets.

What I would like to know is whether the following procedure has security issues (e.g. session session hijacking):

After the authentication procedure a JWT token is generated the client sets the token as query-string property of the SignalR connection. This token is then used for authentication of each request on server side. The procedure is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528221/passing-token-through-http-headers-signalr) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26538699/3737186).

According to the documentation provided [here](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security) (see 'CSRF mitigations taken by SignalR') SignalR does use the query-string already internally for authentication inside the library.

My question is whether it is secure to add my JWT token to the query-string and use it for authentication.